# Install-WindowsFeature specify sub-features

Tags: powershell

When installing a Windows feature:

```
Install-WindowsFeature -Name Web-Server -IncludeAllSubFeature -Verbose:$false
```

How can I specify only required sub-features? E.g. .NET Extensibility 3.5, ASP.NET 3.5, Application Initialization etc. for Web-Server.

In place of `-IncludeAllSubFeature`.

Comment: Shouldn't `Get-WindowsFeature` give you the sub features, which you then could Enable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `install-WindowsFeature -Name  Web-DAV-Publishing` ,once you get the subfeature name from `get-windowsfeature` , as @Clijsters rightly suggested

You can also use [DISM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14) for that:

```
Dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-CGI /Featurename:IIS-websockets
```

Powershell version for the above command:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "IIS-serversideincludes","IIS-applicationinit"
```

To get the feature names, you can use `Dism /online /Get-Features | Select-String socket`